# How to get header text from gridview without fixing the columns

Tags: c#

I want header text from grid view
 I have tried this
 string header = GridView1. Columns[j].HeaderText;
 It returns 0

 i want column name

Comment: That looks like the correct syntax according to the documentation and other examples online. Are you sure you are using the correct column index for the column header you are expecting to read?

Answer (score 0):

Hey brother you can use  below code

```
string str=grdPatient.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Text;
```

Comment: @user2986339 if it is working then please mark it so it becomes helpful to other..